# Запуск iso Windows 10 в Virtual Box

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

Windows Server 2008 32.

Пытался запускать iso Windows 10 в Virtual Box - что то не вышло

> The native API dll was not found (C:\Windows\system32\WinHvPlatform.dll) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE). VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).).

С образом linux такое же название ошибки.

Подскажите что это и как это решить. Спасибо.

Comment: Включите виртуализацию в настройках BIOS

Comment: Спасибо. Проверить к сожалению не смогу, сервер рабочий. Но что можно попробовать учту.